# How do you find the highest-rated win of a certain player?

Tags: software, fide, rating

I'm looking for a tool where I can input a name (e.g. Hans Niemann, Levy Rozman, Eric Rosen etc.) and it will tell me the highest rated player they beat in chess (FIDE rated games). I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3):

No such tool exists. You will have to write it yourself. Here is what you need to do:

1. Go to the "Individual Calculations" page for the player you are interested in. For Hans Niemann that is [here](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/2093596/calculations).
2. You will see the word "available" for each month/time control combination where he has FIDE rated games. Click on one of these, for instance [Standard/September 2022](https://ratings.fide.com/calculations.phtml?id_number=2093596&period=2022-09-01&rating=0).
3. There you will see that he had two wins against Kobalia(2578) and Idani(2641). Record these as you wish.
4. Rpeat for all periods where results are "available" for the time control(s) you are interested in.

I would suggest you write a program to do [screen/data scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping) to speed this up.

Comment: Hmmmmm... interesting I'll consider it. Thanks!

Comment: even with this approach you can read only records after april 2008

Comment: data scraping is not the best answer. downloading a game dump which recorded player ELO is much simpler

Comment: I wonder why you write "no such to exists" when there is ChessBase that has been built specifically for this and similar purposes.

Comment: @Hauptideal this is true only for the games that get into chessbase mega database

Comment: @cmgchess which is true for almost every single game of relevance (i.e. classical tournament/league games). There is no DB that is even remotely as good or comprehensive as the ChessBase, therefore it's the best chance to get the correct answer... I'm pretty sure OP wasn't asking for random lichess blitz games.

Comment: @Hauptideal absolutely! but i'd be more interested in to see who my best win was :P

Answer (score 1):

If you have Chessbase:

1. Step one: [Filter](https://en.chessbase.com/post/fun-and-instructive-the-new-search-mask-in-chessbase-15) every game played by your player and the result (i.e. your player won; you can do this for White and Black separately and merge the results, but you shouldn't even need to).
2. Step two: Sort by rating.

That's it.

Comment: unfortunately, that "if" is the caveat... Good answer though...

Comment: @fartgeek the same thing can be done using chessbase players website. there is also a search option in there. https://players.chessbase.com/en/player/Niemann_Hans%20Moke/363841 . A downside of this is not only fide rated games get in here. games such as titled tuesdays, serious online events  get in here

Answer (score 1):

This is possible to do with scid vs pc (free and open source) as follows

- Load a database (e.g., caissabase, which is free)
- filter games in which player X plays white and wins
- in the filtered collection in the game list window click on the button 'black elo' to sort the collection by black elo.

Do the same by filtering games in which X plays black and wins.

Comment: You need the Chessbase to do this, as this is the only comprehensive database, and it's not free. You might miss the highest-rated win of a player just because it's not in the free DB.